# Problems when installing kernel 3.6.6.

Tags: kernel

Today I downloaded and installed latest version of kernel 3.6.6 from this site 
[kernel.org](http://kernel.org/) on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.

But when I used this command to update:

```
$ apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I found it updating the previous version 3.5.0-18 and I don't know why.

[image]

I want know if when install newer version of kernel must be older one remove automatic?

Comment: I think you should not install kernels that are not yet support on Ubuntu. For what reason you need to install this version?

Comment: thanks you man for help but i think that this version is recommended because this default linux kernel site and this version put under stable version thanks for advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually installing a mainline kernel does not uninstall the old one. They are considered as different packages and therefore the old kernel will still continue to be upgraded.

In any case, Ubuntu will continue booting from the new kernel by default.

The new kernel will NOT be upgraded automatically unless you installed through a PPA.

You should try installing a newer kernel only if you have specific problems with the current one and would like to try to test a newer kernel to see if the problem has been fixed or not. It's not recommended to install an upstream kernel simply to have the latest version, since these are not fully tested and may cause problems.

Comment: thanks you man for help i just download this kernel because i see it is stable not tested or mainline so i download it but i will download any kernel unless i face problem thank you for help

Comment: I'm glad this helped you. If you recognise it as the correct answer, why don't you tick it as such to help other users?

Comment: sorry man i forget i'm very very sorry thanks for remember me